# Please help identify this SMPS IC

Tags: integrated-circuit, switch-mode-power-supply, pwm, identification, surface-mount

I need to repair a charger for an e-bike. The model is SHC-8100L made by stchargers.com.

The unknown IC (marked U1 here, a 3x2 mm SMD IC marked 71427) seems to be faulty.

[image: Part of charger - IC removed marked in red]

Input voltage seems to be on pin 6 only (there is 12 V), other voltages seem to be zero.

Does anyone knows what IC it is?

[image: I added a better size]

[image]

[image: with IC]

---

[image: I added a better size]

I added a better size of picture

---

2MB picture size is a maximum I am allowed to post here.
Here is a bigger https://imgur.com/a/ntZTYT6 (about 4.3 MB)

And here is a crop of the interesting part:
[image]

Comment: Can you upload higher resolution versions of the pictures? You can't make out any details. A macro shot of part in question would also go a long way.

Comment: As I interpret the layout, the pin functions are: 1 GND, 2 FET-DRV, 3 Current sense, 4 ?, 5 Feedback, 6 VCC. The voltage at pin 5 should not be 0 V, there is a resistive divider attached. Are you sure the chip failed?

Comment: Bguy - Hi, You wrote an "answer" but it was actually another photo, not a solution, so it has been added to your question as an edit (i.e. an update) instead. || Since you asked the question, unless you are writing the *full & final* answer to your own question (i.e. unless you don't need further help & you solved the problem yourself using a different solution than any other answer) please don't use the box labeled "Your Answer" below. Instead, to add more info / clarification, please [edit] the question. Or *comment* to respond to an answer. || Please see the [tour] & [help]. Thanks

Comment: I put a better resolution
https://imgur.com/a/ntZTYT6

Comment: @Bguy - Please immediately **stop** writing non-answers as answers. Please read my comment just above this one. As your non-answers get deleted, this is harming the reputation on your account and may lead to an automatic answer-ban soon. Do not treat this site like a typical forum. The text entry box at the bottom of the page is labeled "Your Answer" and is for *answers only*. As I said, please read my comment just above this one for more details of site etiquette. Edit the question, if you want to improve it or add more details. Thanks.

Comment: the "higher resolution" picture is actually much lower resolution because it is out of focus ... the first picture is much clearer

Comment: There is no need to upload a 4.3MB image. Just crop the interesting part (as I did with my edit). Also, there is no need for 5 birds-eye-views of the same. We'd much rather see a close-up picture of the part itself including its markings.

Comment: The only reference to the marking and the package (I assume SOT-23-6) is a mysterious part from a manufacturer called "HAN-GO". I found at least 3 sketchy looking Chinese sites that reference that part [1](https://www.transistorsmosfets.com/transistor?search=71427) [2](http://www.1stchip.com/en-US/ic-71427.html) [3](https://www.114ic.com/71427/hotic5-17528838.html), but none of the sites give any information at all. No even what this parts function is. I also couldn't find anything about the supposed manufacturer "HAN-GO", only a [logo](https://product.11467.com/info/3393050.htm).